# Метод Post и PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Не работает добавление с формы html в бд, помогите пожалуйста
Метод POST в dobavka.php

```
<form class="formserverback" action="dobavka.php" method="POST" >
                    <input size=50 type="text" name="Prozvon" placeholder="Прозвонен ли абонент?">
                    <input size=50 type="submit" name="dobavka" value="Отправить">
    </form>
```

Добавление записи в бд

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['dobavka'])) {
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "vgnuchz_auts";
    $password = "Mboze20013!";
    $database = "vgnuchz_auts";
   

    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
  
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $Prozvon = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Prozvon']);
    
    $password = md5($password);
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Contagent (Prozvon) VALUES ('$Prozvon')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if (!$conn) {
        die('Error: ' .mysqli_error());
    } else {
       echo "Vashi dannie uspeshno zaneseni ReplyCenter";

       mysqli_close($conn); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») **должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку** и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Answer (score -2):

Не срабатывает условие isset($_POST["dobavka"], ибо такого значения действительно не существует, вместо этого у тебя "Prozvon" в поле name.

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что необходимо заменить isset($_POST["dobavka"] на isset($_POST["Prozvon"] и все заработает?

Comment: @МихаилДужарь так сделай `print_r($_POST)` да посмотри, что там приходит.

Comment: Array
(
    [prozvon] => Прозвонили
    [dobavka] => Отправить
) Примерно такое сообщение выходит

Comment: Поменял наименование на prozvon, теперь выдает значение - prozvon - отправить и не более